# Azure Table Storage Incremental backup to Azure Storage Blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azcopy

Is there any way I can do Azure Table Storage backup in to Azure Blob incremental way. AZcopy has solution for full backup for the table but not incremental.

Is there any way I can recover Azure storage table, If I delete it from Azure storage explorer?

Answer (score 1):

We wrote a .[NET library](https://github.com/Luminis-Arnhem/AzureStorageBackup) that backups tables and blobs. You can easily implement this in an azure function timer trigger.

In this [blog](https://sharing.luminis.eu/blog/backup-azure-storage-using-azure-functions-in-3-easy-steps/) I explain how to implement it using an Azure function.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
  var sourceAccountName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BackupSourceAccountName");
  var sourceKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BackupSourceAccountKey");

  var backupAzureStorage = new Luminis.AzureStorageBackup.BackupAzureStorage(sourceAccountName, sourceKey, log, context.FunctionAppDirectory);

  var destinationAccountName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BackupDestinationAccountName");
  var destinationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BackupDestinationAccountKey");
  var destinationContainerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BackupDestinationContainer");

  // Backup Tables
  await backupAzureStorage.BackupAzureTablesToBlobStorage("table1,table2", destinationAccountName, destinationKey, destinationContainerName, "tables");

  // Backup Blobs
  await backupAzureStorage.BackupBlobStorage("container1,container2", destinationAccountName, destinationKey, destinationContainerName, "blobs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently azure doesn't support auto backup the table data into blob.

We need write codes to achieve this requirement.

I suggest you could use azure webjobs/function or azcopy(as you says) to achieve this.

If you want to achieve auto backup the data.

I suggest you could try to use timer trigger function to run codes which could backup the data every day or every minute.

More details about how to use timer trigger, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)(azure function) or [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger)(web jobs).

Comment: I want to backup incrementally. I can write a batch file with azcopy in it and set up a task scheduler and get the backup periodically, but is there a way to filter data to backup just today's data daily instead of wasting bandwidth in downloading the entire table to blob again and again?