# Azure table storage incremental backup

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Is there any way to do Azure Table Storage backup in to an another Azure Table Storage incrementally. AZcopy has solution for full backup for the table but not incremental.

Answer (score 1):

We don’t not support backup of Azure Tables currently, and we may not be doing that in the near future
Going forward future Table investments will be in Cosmos DB. See the documentation for [Azure CosmosDB online backup and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore)
There is a similar thread discussion in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437051/azure-table-storage-incremental-backup-to-azure-storage-blob) link, this provides some idea on your scenario

Comment: Any update on the above answer?
Does Microsoft today support any way of Backing Up Azure Storage Tables? Besides the outdated AzCopy 7.1 which requires reducing TLS Security on the storage account in order to work?